# PatternSyntaxException in android

Tags: java, android

I have this line in my script

```
 listMainString = inputLine.split("}]},");
```

and i get this error:

```
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1: }
```

Any solution?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape all characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

```
listMainString = inputLine.split("\\}\\]\\},");
```

Comment: the first reference I found didn't include } as a special character. The second one did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
listMainString = inputLine.split("}\\]},");
```

control characters used in regex expressions should be escaped to have meaning.